# Need help adding a custom class to classpath

Tags: java, classpath

or at least I think that's the method I need to use. In my class we are learning graphics, but my professor said we couldn't handle the full extent of java graphics just yet so we're using this custom class that was written by somebody called DrawingPanel. I downloaded DrawingPanel.java, my question is how do I get it so that I can import it to be used in my code. So far I've tried just setting my classpath to the folder it and the .class file are in and typing import DrawingPanel; but that didn't work, nor did turning it into a jar file and setting the class-path in manifest to java.awt.jar. and then importing java.awt.*; but that was just a long shot that I didn't expect to work because I have no clue how the manifest.MF works. Can anyone help? edit: also I'm on linux

Comment: Can you post the first line of DrawingPanel.java?  It should be `package something.something;`  I'm asking because it sounds like you're using command line tools, and it's going to involve putting the file into the proper package folder and calling `javac` on the whole directory.

Comment: It actually doesn't have a package

Comment: Okay, that makes it simpler.  Can you post what you've tried so far (i.e. what command are you running)?

Comment: You can't import a class without a package.

Comment: @PeterLawrey If his class is also in the default package, he won't need to explicitly import it (because they're in the same package).  I think this is a problem with his compilation process.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean, but the code I'm trying to compile is just calling a new DrawingPanel object and I compile with javac. When I import java.awt.* it compiles fine but then when I execute the .class with the command java it gives me an error. When I try to just import DrawingPanel it won't compile.

Comment: Okay, so right up front:  Post the error you're getting or we can't give specific help.  Also, you shouldn't need to import `DrawingPanel` (assuming your class is also in the default package).  When you compile, both *.java files should be in the same directory and you'll need to run a command like `javac DrawingPanel.java MyCode.java`.  I'm still posting this as a comment because your question isn't detailed enough to give a full answer.

Comment: I just moved the .java into the same file that I was executing from and it worked. But I would still like to know how to achieve something like what I was trying to do before if it's a feasible thing. Is the error code still pertinent?